# What is the meaning of "чучай, белай" in the carol "Коли ясна звізда в небі засвітила"?

Tags: значення-слів

From the carol [*Коли ясна звізда в небі засвітила*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhaEHUWOsTI):

> Коли ясна звізда
>   з неба засвітила,
>   Тоді пречистая Діва
>   Сина породила.
>   Сина породила,
>   в ясла положила:
>   “**Чучай, белай**, Сине Божий,
>   бо я би  вже спала.”

What is the meaning of *чучай, белай*? I have found no entries on [Ukrlit.org](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on sources below "чучай-белай" is a regional words specific to lulabies. Other similar words are "люляй", "люлі", etc.

Here, in [ua-mova community](https://ua-mova.livejournal.com/183411.html) people say that Hungarian "beli" means "люлі" and "чучай" is likely to mean "засинай" and also possibly has hungarian origin.

Also there is a version of this carol where *"чучай, белай, Сине Божий"* is replaced with *"люляй, люляй мій синочку"*.

There is also another [source](https://studlib.info/hozyaystvo/2347918-dityachiy-folklor/) which suggests that in Transcarpathia (Закарпаття) region, the word *люлі* has synonyms *"чуч-беле, гайчі"*. The words *люлі люлечки*, *люлята*, *чучай-белай*, or just *а-а-а* typically occur in the beginning or ending of a lulaby:

> Колискові пісні ... Належать до найдавніших оберегів. ... Характерні слова *люлі* (зустр. в інших жанрах), на Закарпатті (***чуч-беле***, *гайчі*). Як правило, мають вступи-заспіви та кінцівки (*люлі люлечки*, *люлята*, ***чучай-белай*** або слова *а-----*).

Other lulaby [example](https://dspace.uzhnu.edu.ua/jspui/bitstream/lib/100/1/%D0%97%D0%92%D0%98%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%87%20%D0%A2%D0%90%20%D0%9E%D0%91%D0%A0%D0%AF%D0%94%D0%98%2C%20%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%92%27%D0%AF%D0%97%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%86%20%D0%97%20%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%94%D0%96%D0%95%D0%9D%D0%9D%D0%AF%D0%9C%20%D0%94%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%98%2C%20%D0%92%20%D0%A1%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%A5.pdf):

> **Чучай-белай**, малий хлопець,
>     Не будь такий, як ти отець,
>   Лем будь такий, як ти мати,
>   Не будуть ти люди лати.
>
> <sup>cit. by Пойда С. «Колишу тя, не лишу тя…»: колискові пісні / С. Пойда. – Ужгород: ПП М. М. Басараб, 2008.</sup>

---

Upd: Search for "чуч-беле" also gives additional sources ([this](https://wiki.svit.in.ua/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96) and [this](http://esu.com.ua/search_articles.php?id=4075)) with same info:

> Майже у всіх колисанках незалежно від змісту є заспіви та приспіви: «люлі», «люлесі», «люлечки», «а-а-а» та їхні різноманітні поєднання, а на зх. укр. етніч. зем­­лях (Лемківщина, Пряшівщина) – **«чуч-беле»**, «гайчі», які задають ритм співу, пов’язують в одне ціле різні за змістом фрагменти, що іноді бувають самост. поспівками.

They also reference the following books:

- Літературознавчий словник-довідник / Р.Т.Гром’як, Ю.І.Ковалів та ін. – К.: Академія, 1997. – 752 с.
- Довженок Г. В. Україн­сь­кий дитячий фольклор. Віршовані жан­ри. К., 1981
- Дитячий фольклор: Колис­кові пісні та забавлянки. К., 1984
- Железняк М. Г. Цілюще джерело маминої пісні // Культура слова. 1991. № 40.
- та ін.